# PL/SQL - Trying to create a simple procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

EDITED :
I am trying to create a procedure where a Ref Cursor is defined as an OUT parameter, my question is how do I call out that Ref Cursor when I execute it for example here is how I want to call it in my EXEC sql command :

```
EXEC film_not_in_stock(2,2,vcur);
```

Here is the procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE film_not_in_stock( p_film_id IN NUMBER, p_store_id IN NUMBER, vcur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
     cur sys_refcursor;
     v_cur inventory.inventory_id%TYPE --or the same type the inventory_id column is
     v_cur sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
     OPEN cur FOR SELECT inventory_id
     FROM inventory
     WHERE film_id = p_film_id
     AND store_id = p_store_id
     AND inventory_id NOT IN (SELECT  inventory_in_stock(inventory_id) FROM dual);
     fetch cur into v_cur;
     EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
END;
/
```

I know there are typos in procedure as well, will appreciate if you can help me put it right.

Thank you very very much !!

Tonya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as

```
variable p_cursor REFCURSOR;
DECLARE
BEGIN
film_not_in_stock(2,2,:p_cursor);
end;
 /

print p_cursor;
```

And modify procedure as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE film_not_in_stock (
   p_film_id    IN     inventory.film_id%TYPE,
   p_store_id   IN     inventory.store_id%TYPE,
   vcur            OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
   OPEN vcur FOR
      SELECT inventory_id
        FROM inventory
       WHERE     film_id = p_film_id
             AND store_id = p_store_id
             AND inventory_id NOT IN
                    (SELECT inventory_in_stock (inventory_id) FROM DUAL);
END;
/
```

Comment: Great thanks !! but there are some obvious typos in my procedure can you please help me correct them to put it right - thanks !!

Comment: @TonyaLepski See my updated answer. Of course I do not have clear picture about your sql where condition part as I cannot test it without table description or data.

Comment: Wonderful - Thank you very very much !! Appreciate your help !

Comment: I can not find an option here to accept an answer, can you please show me how ? - Thanks

Comment: Accept an answer wherein tick mark on the left side is clicked which will highlight in green colour.

Answer (score 2):

The following will do :

```
var results refcursor
exec film_not_in_stock(2,2,:results);
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please have a look at my procedure code which is not compiling, please help me correct it - Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a variable to fetch your cursor results into...

Something like this...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE film_not_in_stock( p_film_id IN NUMBER, p_store_id IN NUMBER, p_film_count OUT NUMBER, cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
     cur sys_refcursor;
     v_cur inventory.inventory_id%TYPE --or the same type the inventory_id column is
BEGIN
     OPEN cur FOR SELECT inventory_id
     FROM inventory
     WHERE film_id = p_film_id
     AND store_id = p_store_id
     AND inventory_id NOT IN (SELECT  inventory_in_stock(inventory_id) FROM dual);
     --SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO p_film_count FROM dual; <<----- **This is the line**
     fetch cur into v_cur;
     EXIT WHEN %NOTFOUND;
     --do whatever you want
END;
/
```